# Browser Saved Password Doesnot Load on page loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Ruby on Rails app.I am using Devise for authentication.I have set a 30 minutes timeout for the users which auto logs out the users on 30 minutes of browser inactivity.The problem I am facing is that when the session logs out on timeout after 30 minutes,it takes to the login screen and the browser saved email address and password shows up in the login text boxes.But on clicking the login button it doesn't logs me into the application.When the page reloads after the login fail,I can login as usual.
When i checked the problem further,I found that the email address and password values are nil even though it shows up on the browser screen.

The Login form code is given below:

```
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name,:role => "super_admin")) do |f| %>

    <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "EMAIL", :data => { :'placeholder' => 'EMAIL'}, :class => 'with_holder' %>


    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "PASSWORD", :class => 'disablecopypaste with_holder' , :data => { :'placeholder' => 'PASSWORD'}%>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>

          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>


  <% end -%>


    <a id="save_post" href="javascript:void(0);">LOG IN</a>





<%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
      <%= link_to "FORGOT PASSWORD?", new_password_path(resource_name, :role => 'super_admin') %>
  <% end -%>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?it would be really helpful if anyone can help me with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Last found out the issue..The issue was in submitting the form,the form was not being submitted in usual method.It as being submitted from a JS method which catches the click event of `<a id="save_post" href="javascript:void(0);">LOG IN</a>` and submits the POST action of its parent form.

The issue was that the form was not being Loaded at the time of the click and hence it was returning empty strings for the email and password fields.Once I changed the method of submitting the form to the usual way ie  putting a form submit button

```
<%= f.submit "LOG IN", :id => "login_submit" %>
```

it works fine

As the button is also an element inside the form,it will only get loaded once other elemts inside the form get loaded,hence it wont return empty strings on clicking the button.

Comment: If you want to go with the JS form submission make sure you add the click handler to the submit button in a `$(document).ready()` call. That way, even if users click the button nothing happens until the page is loaded. You can get smart about this and disable the button by default and enable it after you added the click handler. Or you can go a step further and keep the button enabled, add the click handler at the beginning without waiting for the document load. But in the click handler do the form submission in a `$(document).ready()` call.

Answer (score 2):

If you see Email and Password on your login form when reloading the page, it is the browser behavior, not your Devise. It could be because your input has autocomplete attribute and you have selected to Save Password on your browser. Try setting `autocomplete=off` on your input to see if it helps

Comment: When you set autocomplete=off, what do you see?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here the actual problem is that, even though the email and password are getting populated in the form, the values "$("#user_email").val()" and "$("#user_password").val()" are returning "nil" for 4-5 seconds after the pages get loaded. If we click the Login button in this time span,it will show invalid email and password as the values that gets passed are nil. But if we click the button after 4-5 seconds the values are returned correctly and application will accept the credentials and logs me in.

Comment: Do you have any extensions on your browser? And which browsers are you using?